# how to bind data from nested json object in angular 9?

Tags: angular

I am trying to bind nested json object in my angular application. Here

*component.html file*

```
    <div class="row">
  <ul class=" g-img col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let data of ruleTypeList">
    <li *ngFor="let group of data.AnalyticsGroup; let i = index">
      <div class="object-box noti-box col s s1 home-box" >
        <p>{{data.RuleName}}</p>
       
        <p>{{group.GroupName}}</p>
        <div>
          <p>Overall Count: {{getCount(group.Id)}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am getting repetative id's as shown here. Due to which i cannot get stable overall count.
[image]

*component.ts file*

```
  getCount(id){
   this.service.postGroupInfo(grpId).subscribe((res: any)=>{
 const count = res.Count
 return count

})
    }
```

How can i do it???

Comment: it seems that getCount should be async and return a call for this.service.postGroupInfo(grpId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love using [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) for this kind of problem

#### get-count.pipe.ts

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'
import { Service } from 'yourPath'

@Pipe({
  name: 'getCount',
})
export class getCountPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _service: Service) {}

  transform(grpId: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if(!grpId) resolve(?) // grpId wasn't given with

      this._service.postGroupInfo(grpId).subscribe((response) => {
        resolve(response.Count)
      },(error) => {
         resolve('?') // Something wrong happen
        },
      )
    })
  }
}
```

#### component.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
    //...
    getCountPipe,
  ],
  // ...
})
```

#### component.html

```html
<p>Overall Count: {{group.Id | getCount | async}}</p>
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have **subscribe** inside **transform** method as it may produce memory leak. I would eliminate promise and return **of(null)** or this._service.postGroupInfo(grpId)

Comment: @vitaliykotov I got your point and it's interesting. I'm wasn't aware of this possible memory leak. would you think returning `resolve(await this._service.postGroupInfo(grpId))` could be an improovement ?  Or is it better to subscribe to a pipe and unsebscribe it on delete? If neither of both are good, could you link me to  a page that explaine the `of(null)`? I'll then update my answer

Comment: of(null) it's just an example of what could be returned on error or when grpId is not provided. [of](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) is rxjs operator that creates an observable with provided value. this._service.postGroupInfo also returns an observable, so we should return either of them and there is no need in promise. And don't subscribe to postGroupInfo(grpId), **| async** pipe does it for you and unsubscribes on destroy